# Como abrir um dialog passando um objeto como parâmetro no primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog

Boa noite.

Estou com dificuldades para abrir um dialog passando um objeto como parâmetro.

Alguém sabe como resolver isso?

Comment: Até onde chegaste? O que já tens? Passar parâmetro o que significa? Um exemplo para entender melhor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você foi muito pouco detalhista na sua questão, mas supondo que você tenha um botão e que esse botão abra um dialog. Pra passar um objeto como parâmetro, basta fazer assim:

```
<p:commandButton value="Abre Dialog"
                 onclick="PF('dialogWidget').show()"
                 update=":formDialog">
  <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{nomeBean.objetoReceptor}" value="#{objetoASerPassado}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

Comment: Realmente dei poucos detalhes, mas você interpretou bem.
Inicialmente eu estava tentando fazer desta forma, mas desconhecia este <f:setPropertyActionListener>, daí comecei a tentar usando o openDialog() do RequestContext, sem sucesso.
Porém agora com este exemplo consegui. Obrigado =)